# How can restrict users from changing document's name?

Tags: permissions, document, access

Is there any way I can restrict users from renaming a file in a document library?

The user group has editing rights to the document since we need monthly input from them. It is crucial that the users do not go and change the name of the document since another script is then unable to read the document monthly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on premises, cloud, 2007. 2010, 2013? try adding that to the tags

Answer (score 1):

You are able to do it with custom permission levels.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/05/how-to-create-new-permission-level-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Link is for SharePoint 2010, however 2013 won't be too different.

Rename file is not one of the options though.

However, If a user cannot delete a file, they should not be able to rename it either. Try a custom "no delete" permission :)

Kind regards,

Comment: Ok. thanks. I've got cusomt permission levels created with no delete as one so hopefully that will be enough

Comment: Good luck! You should be able to test it if you create a test user.  Always good to be sure something works before relying on it in production

Comment: Hey Alina, how did you get on? Did this fix the issue for you?